# Retreiving data from local Postgres Database using python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a local postgres database setup in my system with 3 tables students, courses and enrolled( mapping many to many relationship between students and courses). I want to query this database from python through sqlalchemy package however i fail while trying to include the enrolled table which maps the many to many relationship.

This is what i have tried:

```
 DATABASE_URI='postgres+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:port/databasename'
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
 from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,String,Date,Table
 Base=declarative_base()
 from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship,backref
```

Everything till here works and if i exclude the enrolled table below i am able to query the courses and students table separately bur i am not able to add the enrolled table which i created from pgadmin.

```
enrolled = Table('enrolled',
                         Column('students_id',Integer,ForeignKey('students.user_id'),primary_key=True),
                         Column('courses_id',Integer,ForeignKey('courses.class_id'),primary_key=True)
                         )
class students(Base):
    __tablename__='students'
    user_id= Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=Column(String)
    email=Column(String)
    password=Column(String)
    enrolled = relationship('courses',secondary=enrolled,lazy='subquery',backref=backref('courses_enrolled',lazy=True))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<student {}>".format(self.username)

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
class courses(Base):
    __tablename__='courses'
    class_id= Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    classnum=Column(Integer)
    faculty=Column(String)
    subject=Column(String)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<subject {}>".format(self.subject)



from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine=create_engine(DATABASE_URI)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s=Session()
```

Basically if i execute `c=s.query(courses).all()` i get this error:

```
InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

[SQL: SELECT courses.class_id AS courses_class_id, courses.classnum AS courses_classnum, courses.faculty AS courses_faculty, courses.subject AS courses_subject 
FROM courses]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/2j85)
```

Comment: Your `Table` definition is missing the `MetaData` object. See the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table). Also `primary_key` for both columns is not possible!

Comment: I tried changing the things you suggested but still i am not able to query the enrolled table

Comment: Please update the question with the changes

Comment: Can you add your table definition. I've tested the code above with the missing `Metadata` object and table creation via `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` and it's working fine!